# How do I find APN settings to use with a 3rd party SMS app?

Tags: samsung, mms, apn

I'm using an admittedly old (Android 4.0.4) Samsung Galaxy Centura (Tracfone) and I've run into a problem with regards to text messaging. The default "Messaging" app is quite limited and is missing the one thing that I wanted:(group messaging), so I switched to [Textra](http://www.textra.me/) for messaging. Textra is *almost* perfect, except that it won't send or receive an MMS!

I figured it was a simple matter of updating the APN settings, until Tracfone support informed me that this phone "does not have adustable APN settings," and could not help me any further.

I experimented and found that **the stock Messaging app can send/receive MMS**, so it's not a system-wide problem, just a Textra problem. I experimented with a couple of other SMS apps from the Play Store, and they all exhibit the same symptoms. SMS works fine, but MMS fails.

Textra does have a place to input custom APN settings, but I can't seem to find the proper settings anywhere. I googled "APN settings for tracfone" and tried a couple of the common results, but no go. I did find out that the phone is apparently running on the Verizon network, (the gateways ##########@vtext.com and ##########@mypixmessages both work) so I tried Verizon APN settings too, but to no avail.

Any ideas on what steps to take next? Surely it is possible, I'm just missing a piece of the puzzle somewhere. :|

Comment: Did you check in your phone settings under *more networks>mobile network>access point names*? Do you not have that setting?

Comment: The phone does not even have a menu option for APN or access point names.

Comment: So you have *mobile networks* but not *access point names?*

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The only menu option under "Mobile networks" is _data enabled_.

Comment: Can't think of a solution. Just strange that the stock one allows you to send mms but not a third party one, being that they both use the same process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APN setting is missing on Nexus 5 bought from US](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/90188/apn-setting-is-missing-on-nexus-5-bought-from-us)

Comment: Please try solutions mentioned in possible duplicate and edit your question if it doesn't solve

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. I did try the solution mentioned, but dialing that code just gives me a Verizon _"this call could not be completed as dialed"_ answer. This is a US Tracfone being used in the US without a SIM card, so I don't really think its the same issue. As I mentioned in the original post, MMS *does* work with the stock messaging app, just not with Textra.